# Appcellerator Titanium not finding Android devices

Tags: android, windows, titanium, adb, appcelerator

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Appcelerator studio to recognize any devices on Windows 10.

Situation is this, have recently upgraded to Windows 10 from 7 in order to have a go at Windows phone development.

I was able to detect and deploy to Android devices fine on my Windows 7 setup.

ADB finds the Android devices ok in command line mode.

Using the Titanium CLI, "Ti info" states "no android devices connected".

Have set up Android studio as a test, Android devices show up successfully and I've been able to run a "hello world" app to them.

Have set up Appcelerator studio on another Win 10 machine as a test, no joy there either

SDK's seem to be set up ok, can run apps on emulator.

Has anyone out there had any trouble deploying to android on Win 10, are there any known bugs or quirks that could be blocking communication between ADB and Appcelerator studio?

Devices used are LG G3 and Galaxy S6

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that your WIndows 10 is allowed access on the devices in Debugging mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm tapping "yes" on the allow access prompt when connecting, "dev mode" and "allow usb debugging" are all enabled. The weird thing is that adb can see the devices and lists them as authorized yet Titanium studio can't seem to pick this up.

On 3 occasions the devices id's have momentarily appeared in Titanium only to immediately disappear again